# qqplot of inverse Gaussian distribution in r

Tags: r, quantiles, qq-plot, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I wanted to draw a qqline of my data with the inverse Gaussian distribution, however, the line printed does not seem to be right, for details see the picture attached.

someone help me please

thanks
[image: the line is not right, the dots are {data quantiles, inverse gaussian quantiles]

Comment: Problem solved, I qqplot my data with normal inverse Gaussian instead of the wanted one, I just did not know how to declare a special inverse Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing what you are trying to do... You want to assess how your data fits to a theoretical inverse Guassian distribution. For example, your data may be `y`:

```
library(statmod)
set.seed(1234)
y <- rinvgauss(100, mean= 5, dispersion= 0.1) # Obesrved data
```

Assuming you don't have some fixed expectation for the parameters `mean` and `dispersion`, you could estimate them from the data `y` by finding the paramater values that make the invgaussian PDF most likely:

```
fn <- function(par= c(mean, dispersion), data) {
    ll <- -sum(dinvgauss(data, mean= par[1], dispersion= par[2], log= TRUE))   
    return(ll)
}

pp <- optim(par= c(mean= 1, dispersion= 1), fn, data= y)

m <- pp$par['mean'] # 4.85
disp <- pp$par['dispersion'] # 0.1
```

Alternatively, pick values for mean and dispersion that you think are appropriate.

Now you can compare the distribution of the data `y` to the theoretical invgaussian distribution with given mean and dispersion parameters:

```
x <- qinvgauss(seq(0, 1, length.out= length(y)), mean= m, dispersion= disp)
qqplot(x, y, xlab = "Theoretical Quantiles", ylab = "Sample Quantiles")
qqline(y, distribution= function(p) qinvgauss(p, mean= m, dispersion= disp))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, your code is very inspiring, you r definitely a great statistician. given my question has so many unknown factors  and you still get it lol

Comment: Problem solved, I'm new to R so I actually did not know how to declare "function(p) qinvgauss(p, mean= m, dispersion= disp))"  in the qq plot, so I was qqplot my data with normal inverse gaussian all the time.
Thank you again, could you recommend me some book or website for R?